# How to Change Settings To Allow Writing To USB Hard Drive In Debian

Tags: debian, usb-drive, external-hdd, ext3, automounting

I have a external USB hard drive formatted in ext3 that I would like to use with my Debian Jessie system. By default the system will automount a USB hard drive in read-only mode when I plug in the USB cable.

I want to change the settings so that I, a non-root user, can write to an automounted USB external hard drive.

How can I change these setting?

If this question has already been asked and answered (I did looked for a such previously asked question) a link to that answer would be perfect.